# Geotoolkit: connect to EPSG database instead of using epsg.properties

Tags: java, gis

I am using geotk-bundle-referencing-3.1.2.jar to perform crs conversions. I would like to configure the library to read the codes from a database and not from the file epsg.properties (org/geotoolkit/referencing/factory/epsg). I could not find any examples.

This is a pice of code I use to convert:

```
CoordinateReferenceSystem sourceCRS = org.geotoolkit.referencing.CRS
                .decode(from, true);
CoordinateReferenceSystem targetCRS = org.geotoolkit.referencing.CRS
                .decode(to, true);
MathTransform mathTransform = org.geotoolkit.referencing.CRS.findMathTransform(
                sourceCRS, targetCRS, true);
```

I can get the authority factory and prints its class, but I cannot set it:

```
CRSAuthorityFactory f=org.geotoolkit.referencing.CRS.getAuthorityFactory(false);
System.out.println(f.getClass());
```

I get org.geotoolkit.referencing.DefaultAuthorityFactory

I was looking at the class ThreadedEpsgFactory (http://www.geotoolkit.org/apidocs/org/geotoolkit/referencing/factory/epsg/ThreadedEpsgFactory.html) and it seems that it tries to create a datasource reading a file EPSG-DataSource.properties, but I could not make it work. I tried copy this file to user.home and also to org/geotoolkit/referencing/factory/epsg but nothing changed.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, you can use the embedded HQL database with EPSG CRS definitions.

http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/referencing/index.html

Normally you just need to include the correct JAR/artifact, i.e.:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
  <artifactId>gt-epsg-hsql</artifactId>
  <version>${geotools.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

The factory should be discovered automatically then via configurations in `META-INF/services`.

There are also further plugins for different databases - PostgreSQL, Access, the mentioned HSQL.

To troubleshoot:

- Make sure you have the right dependencies on the classpath, the necessary plugin and *only* one that plugin.
- Try to debug/trace, which factory is created and why. Check, which JAR specifies the loaded factory.
- Trace the factory initialization.

All of my problems were normally with wrong JARs I've imported.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I can see it is using the embedded HQL database by default. It is loading the DB in {user.home}/.geotoolkit.org/EPSG/HSQL, using the .sql files that are in the jar (org/geotoolkit/referencing/factory/epsg)

It also getting a different DB connection if I paste the file EPSG-DataSource.properties in {user.home}. And it is ignoring the file epsg.properties all the time, so it is what I wanted.

Thanks